# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at ./src/context/AuthContext.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, express

i was developing a booking app using MERN STACK ,can you please help me in this error

So the error comes in this part of Code in AuthContext.js file

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
}
```

I used the useEffect

```js
export const AuthContextProvider=({children})=>{
  const [state,dispatch]=useReducer(AuthReducer,INITIAL_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(state.user))
  },[state.user]);
```

and the error which comes

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0     at JSON.parse ()     at ./src/context/AuthContext.js

Comment: something has the value of `"undefined"` - or some other string beginning with `"u"` - check what is stored in `localStorage.user` chances are it's the string `"undefined"` ... hint: `localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(undefined))` will cause the issue

Answer (score 1):

Error message indicates that issue is within `JSON.parse` which is used in `INITIAL_STATE`.

You can add guard, something like this:

```
const userLs = localStorage.getItem("user");
const INITIAL_STATE={
  user: userLs ? JSON.parse(userLs) : null,
  loading:false,
  error:null,
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution,but sorry it didnt work .The error is still the same

Answer (score 1):

You should always remember two things when getting an item from your `localStorage` and parsing it:

1. You should *always* handle the case that `localStorage` does not
   have the item you're trying to get. If the item is not there, your
   `localStorage.getItem()` call will return `undefined`.
2. You should *never* pass an invalid JSON object into a `JSON.parse()`
   call. `undefined` is not a valid JSON item.
   So in your case, you should separate out the `localStorage.getItem()` call and probably store it in a variable, and then, only if you get a valid JSON back, pass the variable into your `JSON.parse()` call.

The other answers here have given you example ways of doing this.

If you still get the same error after trying the above, then your stored JSON value maybe corrupted. It's hard to say why without looking at the actual returned item from the `localStorage`. You could probably delete the item from your `localStorage` and start the authentication from scratch, to see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.get` returns undefined which cannot be parsed by JSON.parse. I usually use a function like this which catches the error and returns the value itself as a fallback.

```js
function parse(value){
   try {
      return JSON.parse(value)
   } catch(_) {
      return value
   }
}
```

Comment: so can you please suggest me how should i fix my current code

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not passing the details that you want store in the Local Storage. Please pass the user details as an object(inside curly bracket) in the backend.

Hint: please reconstruct your data then pass